# JS to change image on select form codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Currently when I choose my theme from my settings and submit the form it get theme and then changes the image.

I would like it so that also on my form select them what ever theme I select it then changes the image automatic before I click on save.

I would like a **JS** to change the image to what every is selected in theme.

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
       if (empty($config_template)) {
            $data['config_template'] = $this->configs->get('config_template');
        }

        $data['templates'] = array();

        $directories = glob(APPPATH . 'modules/catalog/views/theme/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            $data['templates'][] = basename($directory);
        }

        $data['image'] = DIR_IMAGE . 'templates/' . $this->configs->get('config_template') . '.png';

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_meta_title', 'Meta Title');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_template', 'Template');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_maintenance', 'Maintenance');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        return $this->load->view('setting/settings', $data);

    } else {

        $config_meta_title = $this->model_setting->edit_meta_title($this->input->post('config_meta_title'));

        $config_template = $this->model_setting->edit_template($this->input->post('config_template'));


        redirect('admin/dashboard');

    }

}
```

**View**

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-setting" class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-template"><?php echo $entry_template; ?></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select name="config_template" id="input-template" class="form-control">
<?php foreach ($templates as $template) { ?>
<?php if ($template == $config_template) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $template; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $template; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $template; ?>"><?php echo $template; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<br />

<!-- Currently gets image from controller -->

<img src="<?php echo $image;?>" alt="" id="template" class="img-thumbnail" />

</div>


</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting your right - you need to submit form only by changing select, not pressing Submit? then you can do smth like this (if you can use jQuery):

```
$('#input-template').change(function(event) {
    $('#form-setting').submit();
});
```

updated, the you need to collect all images for templates you have in PHP code

```
  foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            $template_details = array('name' => basename($directory),
                                      'image' => DIR_IMAGE . 'templates/' . $this->configs->get('config_template') . '.png');
            //here we create array with address and images of a template
            array_push($data['templates'], $template_details);
        }
```

and then display it in HTML - modify  output

```
<select name="config_template" id="input-template" class="form-control">
<?php foreach ($templates as $template) { ?>
<?php if ($template['name'] == $config_template) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $template['name']; ?>" selected="selected" data-img="<?php echo $template['image']; ?>"><?php echo $template; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $template['name']; ?>" data-img="<?php echo $template['image']; ?>"><?php echo $template['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

and then add following jQuery code (JS):

```
$('#input-template').change(function(event) {
        $('#template').attr('src', $(this).find(":selected").data('img'));
});
```

Comment: It changes it but makes form submit redirect me to my dashboard. just need it to change before I click on submit so I can view image first.

Comment: Is there away to use my img place because your image puts that above select form and there us and array error on first option.

Comment: it's hard to add those corrections w/o seeing actual whole page code